# Echo command inside a python script

Tags: python-3.x, shell, echo

I need to echo the value of a variable that is inside a python script, I receive the data through the serial port using that script, save this data in the variable and I need to echo this within the system, this is an example:

```
import serial

from os import system

comport = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)

if __name__=="__main__":
   while True:
    var = comport.readline().dec()
    system('echo "$var" >/tmp/query.txt')
```

But it doesn't work, I can't access the content of the variable, even if I do: `system('echo "$var"')` I can't print on the screen

Comment: `system("echo {} >/tmp/query.txt".format(var))` - `var` should be a string

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using:

```
 f = open ("test.txt", "w")
 f.write (var)
 f.close
```